# SQL Server Reporting Services Report Builder not starting as RemoteApp

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, ssrs, remoteapp, clickonce

A bunch of Users has been given access to a SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting services instance. Due to a policy the users only may access the services through a Remote Desktop instance. We have handed out Remote App links to the Internet Explorer calling the internal `http://reporting/Reports` URL which is working. Users can use the Reporting Server functionality, but they are unable to start the *Report Builder* by hitting the appropriate button:

[image: reporting services web site]

The *Report Builder* comes as a ClickOnce application and clicking the button seems to induce loading the reference (`http://reporting/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application`), but the application is not starting. If the same users log in to a full Remote Desktop session and call the same URI in the Internet Explorer, the *Report Builder* is starting just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a ClickOnce application seems to [*need* Windows Explorer to be running as the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567432/832418).

As a quick workaround, the RemoteApp definition might just call `%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe` instead of the `iexplore.exe` executable. Providing an URI as a parameter to the `explorer.exe` call would set up the RemoteApp session with explorer.exe as the shell and run the default browser (IE) with the URI provided subsequently:

[image: remoteapp definition]

As a result, the Reporting Services ClickOnce start should succeed.

As an alternative, the [standalone executable of the Reporting Services Report Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116) can be installed on the Remote Desktop Session host and deployed to the users as a separate Remote App.